# How many save files can you have in The Legend Of Zelda: Spirit Tracks?

Tags: zelda-spirit-tracks

I am debating whether or not to buy Spirit Tracks for Christmas, but it depends on if you can have multiple save files on the same DS. My sister wants to play it, too, so I probably won't buy it if I can not have separate save files.

How many save files can you have in The Legend of Zelda: Spirit Tracks?

Answer (score 1):

Spirit Tracks has two save slots, just like Phantom Hourglass does.

Comment: Which reminds me, I need to continue my current game of Spirit Tracks.  I got sidetracked by Tri Force Heroes and never finished it.